# How to embed a syntax in a qr code output?

Tags: javascript, php, qr-code

I have designed a program that takes user input number then outputs the qr code but the problem is that I want that input number to be in a syntax like this #144*1*1*user number#. Could anyone help me, please
This the index.php file

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum- 
scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<title>Send Email Example</title>
<style>
.center-block {
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-9 col-md-7 col-lg-5 mx-auto">
<div class="card card-signin my-5">
<div class="card-body">
<h5 class="card-title text-center">Générer Code QR</h5>
<form id="generateQrForm" class="form-signin">
<div class="form-label-group">
<label for="inputEmail">Numéro pour QR <span style="color: #FF0000">*</span></label>
<input type="text" name="qrText" id="qrText" class="form-control" required placeholder="Entrez votre 
numéro pour  générer  QR code">
</div> <br/>
<div id="generatedQr text-center">
<img src="" id="generatedQrImg" class="center-block">
</div> <br/>
<button type="submit" name="generateQrBtn" id="generateQrBtn" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block 
text-uppercase" >Générer QR</button>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="generate-qr-js.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the generate-qr-script.php file

```
<?php
include "library/qrlib.php";
if (isset($_POST['generateQr']) == 'generateQr')
{
$qrText = $_POST['qrText']; // receive the text for QR
$directory = "generated-qr/"; // folder where to store QR
$fileName = 'QR-'.rand().'.png'; // generate random name of QR image
QRcode::png($qrText, $directory.$fileName, 'L', 4, 2); // library function to generate QR
echo "success^".$directory.$fileName; // returns the qr-image path
}
```

Comment: Can't you simply add the prefix and suffix to your `$qrText` variable before you generate the code?

Comment: Can you help me with example please? I app that I am using to read this qr code should automatically detect that it is a callable number.

Answer (score -1):

In your '**generate-qr-script.php**' file, make the following change:

Change this:

```
$qrText = $_POST['qrText'];
```

To this:

```
$qrText = "#14411*" . $_POST['qrText'] . "#";
```